# ADO.NET timing out while trying to run stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

Here is a snippet of the code that is bad:

```
    string storedProcedure = "sp3111Commissions";
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand()) {
    string ConnectionString = CMSLayers.DataLayer.Universal.GetConnectionString();
    ConnectionString = 
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()) {
    //Response.Write(EndDate2.ToString());
    //Response.End();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    //Response.Write(ConnectionString); Response.End(); return null;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ShopID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["@ShopID"].Value = ShopID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters["@StartDate"].Value = StartDate;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value = EndDate;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate2", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters["@StartDate2"].Value = StartDate2;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate2", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters["@EndDate2"].Value = EndDate2;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 1380;

    try
    {
        System.Data.DataSet ds;
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da= new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()) {
        System.Data.DataTable Table = null;

        conn.Open();

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;

        using (ds = new System.Data.DataSet()) {

        da.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Table = ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
        return Table;
        }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }       
    }
    }
```

What's happening is it hanging for about 2 minutes, then finally getting a time out error. However, if I run the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, with the same exact parameters, the data comes back literally instantly.

The "hang" is occurring at the "da.Fill(ds);" line. Anyone have any ideas? This is .NET 2.0, by the way

Comment: What's **inside** that stored procedure?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the stored procedure with something trivial that you know will process very quickly? If that helps, you know it's the stored procedure. If it doesn't help, you know it's your client code.

Comment: Can you include the connection string (without any passwords and other sensitive data of course)?

Comment: @marc_s - It is complex and I could post it if you want me to. But remember, running the stored procedure from within Studio Manager yields a result almost instantly. Which leads me to believe the problem isn't in the stored procedure.

Comment: ColinM: server=<myServer>;database=<myDBName>;UID=sa;Password=mypwd;

Comment: This sounds like the connection pool is full and the new connection is timing out before an available slot in the connection pool becomes available.

Try `exec sp_who` and `exec sp_who2` using management studio to see if there are a load of connections being left open against the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate question?

[SqlDataAdapter.Fill() Timeout - Underlying Sproc Returns Quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769128/sqldataadapter-fill-timeout-underlying-sproc-returns-quickly)

Consider `WITH(NOLOCK)` in your `SELECT` statements.

Comment: Interesting. Let me add NOLOCK's to my joins and see if this solution works for me.